# Generate Deterministic Guid from a List of Guids

Tags: c#, hash, guid

I would like to generate a Guid from a list of other Guids. The generated Guid must have the property that for the same input list of guids the resulting Guid will be the same, no matter how many times I apply the transformation.

Also, it should have the lowest collision possible so different guids at the input generate a different guid at the output.

Can someone help me with this? What should be the best way to go here? It's basically a hash function but over Guids.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some arithmetic on the individual bytes of a Guid - the code below basically adds them up (modulo 256 because of the overflow):

```
byte[] totalBytes = new byte[16];
foreach (var guid in guids) {
    var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        totalBytes[i] += bytes[i];
    }
}
var totalGuid = new Guid(totalBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i thought of something like this, but i have no idea about how many collisions i can expect from this. Also, do you have any idea why the question got downvoted so much?

Comment: As long as the input GUIDs are more or less randomly distributed (which is the case if you're using `Guid.NewGuid()`), you should be safe from collisions. As for the downvotes, you forgot to add the programming language (which made the question incomplete), and there is no source code to see what you have tried. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. For more information on how to ask a question, see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is great and helped a lot, except the order of the Guids does not matter here. I'm looking for a solution where the order does make a difference - will comment here if I find one.

Comment: @Ivan: you can multiply the bytes of the first Guid by 1, the second Guid by 3, the third Guid by 5 and so on, before adding them to the total. Why odd numbers, you might ask? Because both 0*2 = 0 and 128*2 = 0 (byte arithmetic).

Comment: @Glorfindel something like `totalBytes[i] += BitConverter.GetBytes((int)bytes[i] * guidNumber)[0];` where guidNumber is 1, 3, 5?

Comment: @Ivan `totalBytes[i] += bytes[i] * guidNumber` will work already - bytes overflow automatically.

Comment: That's awesome. I had been trying a similar approach but thanks for the tip about odd numbers, I would have struggled without that. I did have to cast to byte like `totalBytes[i] +=  (byte)(bytes[i] * guidNumber)`. Really appreciate!